# Firefox 4/5 table border issue with rules=all

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table, border

Here is a simple table example of using table rules=all with cell borders

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table rules="all">
        <tr>
            <td style="border: red solid 1px;">
                Title
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

In most browsers (including Firefox 3.6) it comes out with a red border round the cell, but in Firefox 5 (and IIRC also Firefox 4) there is no cell border.

Is this a bug in Firefox or is there some variation allowed by the specification?

On a related point, is there any point in using the table rules attribute? It doesn't seem to be deprecated but I can't see it does anything that you couldn't do in CSS. In this case, ASP.NET was generating it automatically otherwise I would never have used it.

Comment: You need to decide what you want, rules or borders?

Answer (score 2):

There is no spec for what rules="all" actually does yet, so pretty much any behavior is "correct".

That said, the current Firefox behavior is to map rules="all" to some border styles in the collapsed border model.  Given the details of that mapping (which are currently in the HTML5 draft at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/rendering.html#tables ), the observed behavior is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The 'rules' are only displayed if there are other `td`'s to separated it from. And then the style information is partly overwritten by the adjacent cells. If you create a 3x3 table like this

```
<table rules="all">
     <tr>
         <td>foo</td>
         <td>foo</td>
         <td>foo</td>
    <tr>
         <td>foo</td>
        <td style="border: red solid 1px;">
            Title
       </td>
         <td>foo</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>foo</td>
         <td>foo</td>
         <td>foo</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

FF5 will draw red lines at the right and bottom of the "Title" cell and the others black. Seems like the style information of upper and more left cells is more powerful.

Hope this helps

Cheers
tannerli

Comment: Ah, I missed that I only needed the extra cell.  That makes more sense!

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the first part - although I was able to make it work by adding *some* kind of border to the table tag:  http://pastehtml.com/view/b35h9852w.html

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_rules.asp), you are recommended to only use CSS for this sort of styling (and I agree).

It does appear to be a bug in Firefox, though.  I can't find a clear explanation either way.